# Close a fancybox using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

After opening a jquery fancy box i'am trying to keep the iframe's content light as much as possible by avoiding the reload of jquery package. so i want to close the fancy box (iframe) using pure javascript, i've tried `window.close();` but nothing happened.

Comment: did you try `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();`

Comment: `fancybox` is nothing more than `<div>` with inner content. And FancyBox plugin is for jQuery, you can't use jQuery without actual jQuery

Comment: TypeError: parent.jQuery is undefined
i didn't load jquery package

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to close fancybox on button click from the iframe.

for that you have to do a code like this.

Add this button in your iframe page.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="btnCancel" onclick="self.parent.CloseFancyBox()">Cancel</button>
```

write down below function in your parent file.

```
function CloseFancyBox() {
    $.fancybox.close();
}
```

If you want to close without click a button then you can directaly right below function in your iframe page.

```
function closeFancy(){
 self.parent.CloseFancyBox();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. `window.close();`  do the job 
thank you for your answers